# Spinner design in Android

Tags: android

Hi Friends I need a Help To modify in Spinner Design.I am using Simple Spinner,When i call xml other file in Background its not showing proper.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="medicine_prompt">Choose a Medicine</string>

    <string-array name="medicine_arrays">
        <item>Strepcil</item>
        <item>Adoxa</item>
        <item>Benadrill</item>
        <item>Methamphetamine</item>
        <item>Crack Cocaine</item>
        <item>Ciclosporin</item>
        <item>Mesalazine</item>
        <item>Decold</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>

<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"`enter code here`
        android:layout_width="150sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />
```

Comment: Atleast tell what design you are looking for?

Comment: When i modify spinner in design.that time Drop down Arrow is not showing.i want to display arrow and also some modification in spinner,Like i want to use gradient and ect.

Answer (score 0):

```
Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
            items);

    aa.setDropDownViewResource(
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin.setAdapter(aa);
```

If you're using this code, then you can easily see where the layout can be changed. If it is something sled that you seek, please name it.